# Get the Windows system directory from a .NET Standard library

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, .net-standard

Seems like a simple question, but Google doesn't seem to have an answer for me.

In .NET Framework, we can use `Environment.SystemDirectory` to get the system directory (which will look something like `C:\WINDOWS\System32`), but that property does not exist in the current versions of .NET Standard or .NET Core.  Is there a way to get that folder in a .NET Standard (or failing that, .NET Core) library?

For my purposes it is not required that the call return something useful on non-Windows platforms (and what would it return anyway?  `/lib`?  `/usr/lib`?  etc.), although I guess it would be cool if it did.

Right now it seems like my best option is try to use `C:\WINDOWS\System32` directly, and if that doesn't exist, then try to use `C:\WinNT\System32`, but it feels like such a hack to do it that way.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/release/1.0.0/src/mscorlib/src/System/Environment.cs#L364 ?

Comment: Windows can be installed on other drives, you cannot hardcode c:\

Comment: But what's the intention to locate that folder? A .NET Standard class library should assume itself running on any platform, not only Windows.

Comment: @LexLi I think that a .Net Standard library can have some platform-specific code, as long as it ensure that such code runs only on the right platform, for example using `RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(Windows)`.

Comment: Be cautious about referring to the system directory, there are few legitimate reasons to do so and it is easy to wind up with code that only works on some Windows versions or that fails under unexpected circumstances.  In particular, on 64-bit Windows, if your code winds up running as a 32-bit application (perhaps because it was launched from one) you'll be looking at the syswow64 directory without realizing it.

Comment: @svick "can do" does not mean "should do". Platform specific code still should live in platform dependent class libraries and being loaded into the final apps only when a certain platform is present, IMHO.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I may be able to rewrite this section later but for now I am minimally updating existing .NET Framework code to work under .NET Core, so my goal is to keep the functionality as-is.  The code is detecting whether a third party dll which installs itself in a non-standard subdirectory of System32 is present or not, which seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @LexLi But don't you end up with the same problem, just at a lower level?  Even if I have the top level library selectively load a Windows-only or Linux-only library, they will all need to be .NET Standard to be compatible (right?), so the Windows-only version of the internal library would still have this problem.

Comment: @GrandOpener I think Xamarin has already answered that challenge a long time ago with PCL based Xamarin.Forms and its dependency service, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/ At which level you make the abstraction, and how you map it to individual operating systems matters a lot in program design. I do believe .NET Standard/PCL things should themselves be platform neutral.

Comment: @GrandOpener, yes, that sounds like one of the rare legitimate use cases.  (Well, a purist might argue that you shouldn't be using broken third-party libraries, but sometimes there's no reasonable alternative.)  Regarding the syswow64 redirection in particular, if your code is running as 32-bit it wouldn't be able to use a 64-bit DLL anyway, so the redirection won't hurt and might even be desirable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[.Net Core 2.0 (and .Net Standard 2.0) will contain `Environment.SystemDirectory`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Environment.SystemDirectory), but the current 1.x versions don't.

Though the property still exists as `internal`, so one workaround would be to access it using reflection, if you're willing to rely on non-public code:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using static System.Reflection.BindingFlags;

…

var systemDirectory = typeof(Environment).GetProperty("SystemDirectory", NonPublic | Static)
    .GetValue(null, null);
```

On my Windows 10 machine with .Net Core SDK 1.0 running on .Net Core 1.1.1, this returns `C:\WINDOWS\system32`. Running the same code on Ubuntu 16.04 results in `NullReferenceException`.